# d.collection in not a function in production environment with nongoclient async waterfall nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting following error in production environment I have tested this code in staging and dev environment but its causing a error in production environment only

```
#node /home/abc/xyz/current/packages/omi-worker/bulk_load_devices.js


Error:

There is error while connecting to mongo client
/home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:456
            throw err
            ^

TypeError: db.collection is not a function
    at /abc/xyz/viewpoint/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/src/device.js:71:14
    at nextTask (/home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi worker/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5297:14)
    at next (/home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:5304:9)
    at /home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:906:16
    at /abc/xyz/viewpoint/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/src/device.js:63:15
    at connectCallback (/home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:505:5)
    at /home/abc/xyz/releases/20170630032343/packages/omi-worker/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:453:13
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Following are the snippet of node script which process some data in temporary hash and create mongodb connection and inserting a data into database

```
     #!/usr/bin/env node

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var service = require('./service');
var service_1 = require('./service_1');
var service_2 = require('./service_2');
var database = require('./../utility/database');
var fs = require('fs');
var moment = require('moment');
var GLOBAL = require("./../config/global");
var _ = require('lodash');
var async = require('async');
var log4js = require('log4js');
var path = require('path');
var logFilepath = path.join(__dirname, './../config/log4js.json');
var logConfig = fs.readFileSync(logFilepath);
log4js.configure(logConfig);
var logger = log4js.getLogger('bulk_load_devices');
var mongo_server = GLOBAL.MONGO_SERVER.url;

module.exports = {
  bulkLoad: function() {
    async.waterfall(
      [
// Update devices details from service_1
        function(callback) {
          var big_bacon = service_1.bulkLoad(data);
          callback(null, big_bacon);
        },
        function(big_bacon, callback) {
          var commands = service_1.update_command_table(big_bacon);
          callback(null, big_bacon, commands);
        },
        // Update devices details from service_2
        function(big_bacon, commands, callback) {
          big_bacon = service_2.bulkLoad(big_bacon);
          callback(null, big_bacon, commands);
        },
        // Connect to mongoclient for database operations.
        function(big_bacon, commands, callback) {
          MongoClient.connect(mongo_server, function(err, db) {
            if (err) {
              logger.debug('There is error while connecting to mongo client');
              console.log('There is error while connecting to mongo client');
              callback(null);
            } else {
              callback(null, db, big_bacon, commands);
            }
          });
        },
        // Bulk insert process commands data into temporary command worker.
        function(db, big_bacon, commands, callback) {
          console.log("collection======" + db.collection);
          db.collection(GLOBAL.COMMAND_WORKER).insertMany(commands, function(err, r) {
            callback(null, db, big_bacon);
          })
        }
        ]     ],
      function(err, result) {}
    );
  },

  prepareData: function() {
    var processData = [];
    var deviceData = service.getDeviceList();
    async.each(deviceData, function(device, callback) {
      var currentTime = moment(moment()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z');
      record = {
        guid: device['properties']['guid'],
      };
      processData.push(record);
    });    
    return processData;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.

```
async.waterfall([
    ...
    // Connect to mongoclient for database operations.
    function(big_bacon, commands, callback) {
        MongoClient.connect(mongo_server, function(err, db) {
        if (err) {
            logger.debug('There is error while connecting to mongo client');
            console.log('There is error while connecting to mongo client');
            callback(null); // <<<<<<<
        } else {
            callback(null, db, big_bacon, commands);
        }
        });
    },

    // Bulk insert process commands data into temporary command worker.
    function(db, big_bacon, commands, callback) {
        console.log("collection======" + db.collection);
        db.collection(GLOBAL.COMMAND_WORKER).insertMany(commands, function(err, r) {
        callback(null, db, big_bacon);
        })
    }
],
```

If you can't connect to Mongo then `db`-object is undefined and the following steps did not matter. You must call `callback(err)` instead `callback(null)` to break `async.waterfall` and jump to final callback.

```
    ], // end of waterfall array function

    function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
           // process error here
        }
    }
); // end of async.waterfall
```

Comment: Hey @Aikon Mogwai Thanks for this correction but my problem is I am getting error db.collection is not a function in production environment can you help me here

Comment: `db.collection` is a not a function because `db` is equals to `undefined`. `undefined` doesn't have method `collection` and any others, of course. You have problem to connect to MongoDB on production. You must check db connection parameters and also change code as above.

Comment: Thanks I debug it more I am getting error
error trace==MongoError: failed to connect to server on first connect [MongoError: connection timed out]